# Android app that detects other android device with same app nearby

Tags: android, location

I am looking to develop an application that detects other android devices running the same app nearby(under a range of 300 meters). 
Also , they can communicate with each other through messages and can send files to each other(multichat).

Does QUALCOMM API provides functionality for this ? 
Will it be free or i need to buy them ?
How much would be the cost ?
Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking 10 meters or so, this would be exactly what Bluetooth is for.

If not, then you will have to use GPS. In that case, your app would need to keep track of the user on a server and look for other users around the same coordinates. That will of course affect battery life if you use the exact position, not to mention that there are grave privacy issues.